# How to implement trimming of video which is playing on AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

My requirement is to implement trimming and editing of video which is Playing on AVPlayer

**Trimming**: Can we customize AVPlayer player trimming like which we do in default editing of video through UIImagePickerController .I had found few links on showing progress bar,But here requirement is to display sequence of images there by editing Like default editing of UIImage picker controller

If any knowledge shared might help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have access to a class called [`UIVideoEditorController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/index.html) which allows for movie editing.  [Here is a sample project that shows you how](http://iphone-book-sample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter12/UIVideoEditorControllerSample/).

Separately, [here's a tutorial on how to use AVExportSession](https://iostechie.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/avasset-trim-and-save-video/) to trim AVAssets (you'd likely need to modernize it for ARC).